# How to boot an app in spring integration test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I need to create an integration test for my app. I used `@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})` annotation to boot it, but its launch takes time. So how can i run test, when my app is ready?

The problem is in kafka listener:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

   @Autowired
   private KafkaConsumeHandler kafkaConsumeHandler;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

   @KafkaListener(topics =  "${kafka.topics.test}",  containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenRegistred(KafkaMessage consumeKafka) {
        kafkaConsumeHandler.handleStartProcess(consumeKafka);
}
```

If i try to send messages immediately in test, the listener cant catch them. So i used a little pause before sending.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@DirtiesContext
public class ProcessTest {   

@ClassRule
public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, "testTopic");

@Test
public void sendTestRegistred() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000); // Need a delay to boot an application
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApp {}

@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringApp.class)
public class IntegrationTest {}
```

Also, note that the integration test will always be slower than unit test and you need to determinate what kind of test you need to test a certain functionality.

**Update after updates in question:**
In your case, the delay of the test is caused because of waiting on `KafkaEmbded` to start. So you have to find a way programmatically to determinate when `Kafka` is ready. This is one possibility that should work:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   // wait until the partitions are assigned
   for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : 
        kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {

       ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer,
       embeddedKafka.getPartitionsPerTopic());
   }
```

Code is taken from here: https://github.com/code-not-found/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka-avro/src/test/java/com/codenotfound/kafka/SpringKafkaApplicationTest.java#L42
If this doesn't work look for how to wait on `KafkaEmbedded` start-up. Your problem is not caused by SpringBootTest.

Comment: i had class with @SpringBootApplication and i want to test its API, but it takes time to load it, so when i try to send requests, my app is not ready to accept them. Now i use Thread.sleep in test and i want to change this.

Comment: If you have SpringBootApplication class inside `@SpringBootTest`, then Spring Boot will wait for the application to start before running any tests. You can generate a sample application here https://start.spring.io/ and verify that this is the default behavior. In your case, you have some other thing that is causing a problem and you need to provide more details and code from the project in order to make this a valid question.

Comment: I add details in question